# Carrying a rabbit from France to Austria

Tags: air-travel, eu, pets

I want to travel by plane From Paris to Vienna. And I'll bring my pet rabbit (Netherland dwarf) with me.

But I find little information about regulation for transporting rabbits.

Official site explains very, very well the situation for cats, dogs and ferret (why the heck are they that specific about ferrets??) but just won't say anything about other animal.

Geopolitical situation: France and Austria are part of the EU and Schengen area.

[image: Stich vous remerci]

Comment: I laughed at this question because I've also seen Ferrets specifically called out and also wondered, why Ferrets of all things..?  For clarity, I have no answers for your question... :)

Comment: Do you mean the countries' regulations, or the airline's? I suspect the latter are far stricter than the former in this specific case.

Comment: @Madlozoz I have no experience with this issue. But searching the net for "bring pet to Austria" immediately returned lots of third-party sites discussing the issue. The first site I visited linked to this Austrian government page: https://www.bmgf.gv.at/home/EN/Health/Information_for_Travellers/Entry_and_re_entry_of_pets_from_third_countries_to_Austria. The title of that Austrian govt page is "Entry and re-entry of dogs, cats, ferrets and other pets." The wording "...and other pets" sounds like it includes rabbits.

Comment: Here's California's statement (although it's mostly on hedgehogs), ["To protect public health and safety, agriculture, wildlife, and natural resources, ..."](https://www.wildlife.ca.gov/living-with-wildlife/restricted-pet-species)

Comment: @origimbo I'm trying to figure the national/European law first. But I am aware that a company can refuse my rabbit whatever the law says

Comment: @David Thank you! Searching this website I found this document stating (I think) that rabbit are good to go as long as they accompany me :https://www.bmgf.gv.at/cms/home/attachments/2/2/1/CH1287/CMS1419849395319/travelling_pets_austria_information.pdf  Feel free to make an answer that I will select

Comment: @Madlozoz I agree; that document says domestic rabbits (not for sale or transfer) accompanying the owner are admitted without veterinary certificate.

Comment: The BMGF links are 404 now.

Comment: Ferrets, when wild are prone  to rabies. Abandoned Ferrets in warm area (southern Italy) are not uncommon and hard to distinguish. Thus the listing.

Answer (score 6):

The main page relevant for **EU** (from France) and rabbits in English can be found here:

https://www.sozialministerium.at/siteEN/Health/Information_for_Travellers/Movement_of_other_pets_between_Member_states_of_the_EU_the_EEA_and_Switzerland

It contains a link for an English pdf, where **rabbits (not intended for food production)** is explicitly listed.

**Short summary (from pdf) :**

When entering Austria, private persons may bring any of the listed animals **without** a Health Certificate.

The animal may not be sold or given away to other persons.

The owners are advised to insure that the animal cannot spead any animal diseases and checking with a local official veterinary about current conditions.

---

The German page contains the same information.